# How to start Raspberry normally after changing crontab?

Tags: linux, cron, raspberry-pi3

I've done some changes on crontab to run a python script on startup but now I don't know how to make it go back to normal (boot normally).

@Edit: my raspberry starts, the screen goes black and I can't see/do nothing.

Is there a way to boot like in windows safe mode?

How can I solve this?

Comment: hi @AI777 glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best answer would be to

`crontab -e` then comment out each line you don't want to run with #.